# OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "" was unable to begin a distributed transaction

Tags: sql-server, msdtc

I use sp via link server. I want  insert out put of this sp into  table .
when I run my sp it throw bellow error:

> "The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider
> "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "myLinkServerName" was unable to begin a
> distributed transaction."

```
Declare @Table Table (id int , ...)
INSERT INTO  @Table
EXEC [LinkServeName].BimeDW.dbo.sp_ExecuteSql
```

I search for this error and understand that I should  check "allow inbound" and "allow outbound" for msdtc service but My server work 24 hours a day and I really fear What Happen If I check these two check mark.
I would glad if somebody who can describe for me?

Comment: `sp_executesql` has parameters, but they are missing in the above. I *assume* you are passing something?

Comment: Quite frankly, this is the path you have chosen and you must to this for distributed transactions to work. But linked servers are notoriously fragile and distributed transactions can fail often. Obviously you should attempt this with a test system to understand the effects and whether this path is best for your needs. DTC has been in use for many years - enabling it should not be a big concern (as opposed to actually using it in a reliable manner).

Comment: It seems your MSDTC is not healthy. If you don't need DTC functionality via this linked server, you can set the distributed transactions option to false to avoid DTC involvement:  `EXEC master.dbo.sp_serveroption @server=N'LinkServeName', @optname=N'remote proc transaction promotion', @optvalue=N'false';`. Of course, you'll also need to fix your code as @Larnu mentioned.

Comment: I want to ask an other question. you suggest two ways 1. to enable DTC in server or in SQL  Server, make optvalue false which of them are the best practice. or beter to ask what does dtc do ?

Comment: I don't think there is a singe best practice; it depends on the case. There is no need for DTC with the script in your question because only the table variable is modified, no remote resources are changed, and table variables are not subject to rollback anyway. However, if other queries use the same linked server when require a transaction rollback of changes made to both local and remote tables, the DTC will help that.